# Qt i18n encoding

Tags: qt, character-encoding, internationalization

Is there any difference in the way strings are translated in QT between literal strings in code and strings defined in a .ui file? Besides this, I should able to translate between a UTF-8 string to another UTF-8 string, not just from ASCII, right?

This doubt stems from a bug I found when trying to include UTF-8 characters (formatting characters like '»') in a "source" english string in my .ui file. The result is that the translations for those strings are not picked up by QT.
Note: I didn't forget to update to  tags in the .ts file

Comment: I should've added that I'm using QT4.8 for this